# Flink JDBCInputFormat cannot find method 'setRowTypeInfo'

Tags: jdbc, apache-flink

I want to use flink-jdbc to get data from mysql。
I have seen an example on Apache flink website

```
// Read data from a relational database using the JDBC input format
DataSet<Tuple2<String, Integer> dbData =
    env.createInput(
      JDBCInputFormat.buildJDBCInputFormat()
                     .setDrivername("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver")
                     .setDBUrl("jdbc:derby:memory:persons")
                     .setQuery("select name, age from persons")
                     .setRowTypeInfo(new RowTypeInfo(BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO, BasicTypeInfo.INT_TYPE_INFO))
                     .finish()
    );
```

But when i try to write a demo， i can't find the method 'setRowTypeInfo'.
It was like this

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.BasicTypeInfo
import org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCInputFormat
import org.apache.flink.api.scala._

/**
  * Created by lulijun on 17/7/7.
  */
object FlinkJDBC {


  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {

    val env = ExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment()

    val dbData = env.createInput(
      JDBCInputFormat.buildJDBCInputFormat
        .setDrivername("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
        .setDBUrl("XXX")
        .setUsername("xxx")
        .setPassword("XXX")
        .setQuery("select name, age from persons")
        .setRowTypeInfo(new Nothing(BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO, BasicTypeInfo.INT_TYPE_INFO))
        .finish)

    dbData.print()

    env.execute()
  }

}
```

The "setRowTypeInfo" method is always red, and the IDEA prompts 
"cannot resolve symbol setRowTypeInfo"

The jar version of flink-jdbc i used is 1.0.0.

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Use this dependency if you are using the DataSet API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-scala_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-clients_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.36</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have searched a lot, and most of the people use the method exactly like the official document, but on one mentioned this problem.
I doubt whether I used the wrong version of flink-jdbc, but I cannot get any information about the right way to use flink-jdbc.
If you know the problem, please teach me.Thank you.

Comment: I tried change the flink-jdbc version to flink-jdbc_2.11/0.10.2, and all the other flink jar to scala 2.11.  But still can't find the 'setRowTypeInfo' method.       How can everybody access this method correctly???

Answer (score 0):

I changed the flink-jdbc version from 1.0.0 to 1.3.0 and the problem solved.
But when I search flink-jdbc on maven websit
https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=flink-jdbc, I can't get the right information in the first few pages, It makes me thought the version of flink-jdbc do not need to be matched with other flink jars. 
But the truth is flink-jdbc/1.1.3 use class RowTypeInfo of package api.table, but flink-jdbc/1.3.0 use class RowTypeInfo of package api.java.They have close ties with each other.
We must make sure the version is matched.